# How to bootstrap confidence interval for a weighted KM survival probability in R?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival, weights, kaplan-meier

I'm a grad student trying to calculate the survival probability at a particular time point (in this case at 12 months). In order to deal with differential loss to follow-up (LTFU), I'm assigning weights to the LTFU participants who I was able to trace their vital status and assigning a weight of zero and dropping the LTFU participants who I wasn't able to trace their vital status from the analysis.

The problem is I'm struggling to calculate the confidence interval that takes weighting into account. I think I need to use bootstrapping but I'm not sure how to code this in R.

This is what my data frame looks like:
| Time | event  | weights |
| ---- |--------|---------|
| 6    | 0      | 0       |
| 18   | 0      | 1       |
| 12   | 0      | 2.5     |
| 11   | 1      | 2.5     |
| 9    | 1      | 1       |
| .    | .      | .       |

This is how I get the survival probability at month 12:
summary(survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1, weights = weights, data = df, robust = TRUE), times = 12)

I would really appreciate any help/suggestions.